# PySpark: How to keep only the rows from the left table when dropping duplicates after a full join?

Tags: pyspark

How can I keep the rows that came from the left table when dropping duplicates after a full join? I want to have all rows of both tables, except in cases where there are duplicates, then I throw away the row from the right table.

I have tried the below, but without success:

```py
schema = ["name", "source", "score"]

rows1 = [("Smith", "Acme", 98),
         ("Jones", "Acme", 30),
         ("Finch", "Acme", 62),
         ("Lewis", "Acme", 59),
         ("Starr", "Acme", 87)]

rows2 = [("Smith", "Beta", 64),
         ("Jones", "Beta", 75),
         ("Bryan", "Beta", 93),
         ("Lewis", "Beta", 59),
         ("Starr", "Beta", 81)]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rows1, schema)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rows2, schema)
jdf = df1.alias("a").join(other=df2.alias("b"), on="name", how="full")
jdf = jdf.orderBy("name").dropDuplicates(["name"])
for col in ["source", "score"]:
    jdf = jdf.withColumn(colName=col, col=(F.col("a."+col) if F.col("a."+col).isNotNull() else F.col("b."+col)))
```

The above is invalid and results in this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

The result I am trying to achieve:

```
+-----+------+-----+
| name|source|score|
+-----+------+-----+
|Bryan|  Beta|   93|
|Finch|  Acme|   62|
|Jones|  Acme|   30|
|Lewis|  Acme|   59|
|Smith|  Acme|   98|
|Starr|  Acme|   87|
+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Should the expected output for Jones be: `|Jones|  Acme|   30|`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the close attention to this detail. I will fix the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) function. It returns the first non-null column. So provide the column from the left table first, and then the right table to `coalesce`.

```
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("source", "source2").withColumnRenamed("score", "score2")

from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

df1.join(df2, ['name'], "full").withColumn('source', coalesce('source', 'source2'))\
    .withColumn('score', coalesce('score', 'score2')).drop('source2', 'score2').show()

+-----+------+-----+
| name|source|score|
+-----+------+-----+
|Bryan|  Beta|   93|
|Finch|  Acme|   62|
|Jones|  Acme|   30|
|Lewis|  Acme|   59|
|Smith|  Acme|   98|
|Starr|  Acme|   87|
+-----+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that appears to work: I used a "left-anti" join to get the rows that don't match from the right column, then union that with the left table.

```py
schema = ["name", "source", "score"]

rows1 = [("Smith", "Acme", 98),
         ("Jones", "Acme", 30),
         ("Finch", "Acme", 62),
         ("Lewis", "Acme", 59),
         ("Starr", "Acme", 87)]

rows2 = [("Smith", "Beta", 64),
         ("Jones", "Beta", 75),
         ("Bryan", "Beta", 93),
         ("Lewis", "Beta", 59),
         ("Starr", "Beta", 81)]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rows1, schema)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rows2, schema)

jdf = df2.join(df1, on="name", how="leftanti")
udf = df1.union(jdf)
```